# Reading mail from my outlook account using robotframework

Tags: outlook, robotframework, email

I am using Robot-framework with the ImapLibrary for getting the content of latest mail from my outlook account. The error I get is -

```
**TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'**
```

Can somebody help me out please ?

My code is -

```
*** Settings ***

Library           ImapLibrary

*** Test Cases ***

Email Verification

    Open Mailbox    host=outlook.office365.com    user=myname@company.com    password=secret
    Get Email Body   1
    Close Mailbox
```

Comment: Is this only part of the error message, or all of it?

Comment: @A.Kootstra All of it. Also, I tried changing the exchange server to smtp3.companyname.com where I get the error "[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Answer (score -1):

Try,

```
Open Mailbox    
host=imap-mail.outlook.com     
user=myname@company.com    
password=secret
```